# Is it possible to select multiple object behind an object witch is not a square in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, selections

Context: Im trying to make some shapes, icons in a glitter texture looking realistic as possible.

For this, a large group of objects are placed and way larger object is on top. How is it possible to select all the objects behind this object if this object is not a square (shape of the selector).

I'm not interested in the "set clip" method, because that sharpens the edges and it does not look realistic.

Comment: Hi. As far as I know, there is no native functionality in Inkscape that can use an arbitrary shape to automatically select objects. Might be possible with an extension, but I know of none that can do this